# Installing redis CLI

Tags: redis-cli

I am new to redis and I am installing redis cli, using the below tutorial.

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis
>   this tutorial suggests to do sudo make install after make test, but when I am doing "sudo make install", it give me the below prompt

```
Hint: It's a good idea to run 'make test' ;)

INSTALL install
INSTALL install
INSTALL install
INSTALL install
INSTALL install
```

I do not have any idea whether this will create any problem in installing the cli globally.

Any suggestions on this will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alternatively copy the server and cli application by doing:

```
sudo cp src/redis-server /usr/local/bin/
sudo cp src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
```

as described in the [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart).